# How to read the value of XML tag using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml

How to read the value of Instruction Tag which is "DO IT"

```
 XML BLOB
 <Rate maxRate="HIGH" Type="PROD" situs="DESTINATION" inputOutputType="OUTPUT" FromParty="BUYER">
            <Instruction instructionLevel="DESIGN" instructionId="1234">DO IT</Instruction>

$xml = simplexml_load_string(XML BLOB);
```

Output:

```
$xml->Rate->Instruction = 

object(SimpleXMLElement)[95]
public '@attributes' => 
array (size=2)
  'instructionLevel' => string 'DESIGN' (length=7)
  'instrucctionId' => string '1234' (length=5)
public 0 => string 'DO IT' (length=11)
```

How to extract => DO IT

Comment: `$result = $xml->xpath("Rate/Instruction");` does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your blob with a properly closed `<Rate>` tag:

```
$XML_BLOB = '
    <Rate maxRate="HIGH" Type="PROD" situs="DESTINATION" inputOutputType="OUTPUT" FromParty="BUYER">
        <Instruction instructionLevel="DESIGN" instructionId="1234">DO IT</Instruction>
    </Rate>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($XML_BLOB);
$content = (string)$xml->Instruction;

php > var_dump($content);
string(5) "DO IT"
```

You can access the `Instruction` element using the tag name as an attribute on the object. Just cast it to a string to get the tag contents.

Note that it is not `$xml->Rate->Instruction` because `Rate` is the top level node. More likely your document has a root/top-level node:

```
$XML_DOC = '
    <root>
        <Rate maxRate="HIGH" Type="PROD" situs="DESTINATION" inputOutputType="OUTPUT" FromParty="BUYER">
            <Instruction instructionLevel="DESIGN" instructionId="1234">DO IT</Instruction>
        </Rate>
    </root>';
```

Now you would access it using the expected hierarchy:

```
php > echo $xml->Rate->Instruction;
DO IT
```

---

Alternatively you can use an Xpath expression:

```
$instruction = $xml->xpath("Rate/Instruction");
$content = (string)$instruction[0];

php > var_dump($content);
string(5) "DO IT"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$XML_BLOB = '
    <Rate maxRate="HIGH" Type="PROD" situs="DESTINATION" inputOutputType="OUTPUT" FromParty="BUYER">
        <Instruction instructionLevel="DESIGN" instructionId="1234">DO IT</Instruction>
    </Rate>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($XML_BLOB);

foreach( $xml->xpath("//Instruction/text()") as $url ) {
    echo $url;
};
```